# How to fix: Cannot insert the value NULL into column, insert failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

For school I'm busy writing a stored procedure on my database. Now I get an error when I try to execute it.

I already tried looking on stack overflow for fixes but could not find anything that helps me.

```
create procedure spNieuweBestelling
    (@medewerkerid int,
     @productid int,
     @aantal_producten int)
as
begin
    declare @bestellingsid int
    declare @besteldatum date = getdate()

    select @bestellingsid = max(@bestellingsid) + 1
    from bestelling b;

    begin transaction
        insert into bestelling 
        values (@bestellingsid, @medewerkerid, @besteldatum)

        insert into productbestelling 
        values (@productid, @bestellingsid, @aantal_producten)

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            rollback
            raiserror ('error tijdens de 2de insert',16,1)
            return
        end
    end
    commit

exec spNieuweBestelling 2,2,200
```

Screenshot of the tables: https://prnt.sc/npqhiz

I expect that this procedure will insert into this 2 tables but it keeps raising this error.

Comment: Won't try to into a `NULL` into the column that you're trying to insert a `NULL` into, or change the column to allow the insertion of `NULL`. If the column's value shouldn't be `NULL`, then the statement trying to do the `INSERT` is wrong, and needs to be fixed.

Comment: It cant be a null its a primary key, but i declare the variabele and then look for the max number of this variabele and then do it +1 so it should automatic be a unique number?

Comment: `max(@bestellingsid)` determines the max of `NULL`, because you haven't initialized the variable. And `[something] + NULL = NULL`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/npqlfv, the current max bestellingsid = 1002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo:

```
select @bestellingsid = max(@bestellingsid) + 1
    from bestelling b;
```

Should probably be:

```
select @bestellingsid = max(bestellingsid) + 1
    from bestelling b;
```

But why don't you just use an `IDENTITY`?

Also, since this is for school; When you insert into a table *always* list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO productbestelling (productid, bestellingsid, aantal_producten)
```

Comment: Yes that was the fault. I only had 1 lesson in stored procedures so dont know how to use that yet.